# Why preg_replace throws me a "Unknown modifier" error?

Tags: php, preg-replace, modifier

I keep getting this error:

> Warning: preg_match()
>   [function.preg-match]: Unknown
>   modifier 't' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\administrator\components\com_smms\functions\plugin.php
>   on line 235

on:

```
$PageContent = preg_replace($result->module_pregmatch, '', $PageContent);
```

I do a var_dump on the $result->module_pregmatch and I get the following:

```
string '/<title>(.*)</title>/Ui' (length=23)

string '/<meta[^>]*name=["|\']description["|\'][^>]*content=["|\'](.*)["|\']\s*\/>/Ui' (length=77)

string '/<meta[^>]*name=["|\']keywords["|\'][^>]*content=["|\'](.*)["|\']\s*\/>/Ui' (length=74)

string '/<meta[^>]*name=["|\']author["|\'][^>]*content=["|\'](.*)["|\']\s*\/>/Ui' (length=72)

string '/<meta[^>]*name=["|\']copyright["|\'][^>]*content=["|\'](.*)["|\']\s*\/>/Ui' (length=75)

string '/<meta[^>]*name=["|\']robots["|\'][^>]*content=["|\'](.*)["|\']\s*\/>/Ui' (length=72)

string '/<meta[^>]*http=equiv=["|\']content-language["|\'][^>]*content=["|\'](.*)["|\']\s*\/>/Ui' (length=88)
string '/<meta[^>]*http-equiv=["|\']content-type["|\'][^>]*content=["|\'](.*)["|\']\s*\/>/Ui' (length=84)

string '/<link[^>]*href=["|\'](.*)["|\'][^>]*rel=["|\']shortcut[^>]*icon["|\'][^>]*type=["|\']image\/x-icon["|\']\s*\/>/Ui' (length=114)

string '/<link[^>]*href=["|\'](.*)["|\'][^>]*rel=["|\']alternate["|\'][^>]*type=["|\']application\/rss\+xml["|\'][^>]*title=["|\'](.*)["|\'][^>]\/>/Ui' (length=142)

string '/<link[^>]*href=["|\'](.*)["|\'][^>]*rel=["|\']alternate["|\'][^>]*type=["|\']application\/atom\+xml["|\'][^>]*title=["|\'](.*)["|\'][^>]\/>/Ui' (length=143)
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've been stuck on this error for way too long...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are using forward-slashes as your regex pattern delimeter, so `/<title>(.*)</title>/Ui'` will not work (`</title>` has a forward slash).

You should be able to escape the forward slash or use a different delimiter that is not contained within the pattern, for example

```
'/<title>(.*)<\/title>/Ui' //(esacaping)
```

or

```
'~<title>(.*)</title>~Ui' //different delimiter
```