# Function preg_match() returns nothing

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to use [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) in my code, but the result is nothing ... (or null or empty ?)

```
$domain = "stackoverflow.com";

$uriToTest = "http://stackoverflow.com/";

$pattern = "/^http(s)?://(([a-z]+)\.)*".$domain."/";

echo preg_match($pattern, $uriToTest);
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I think you got an error, yes?

Comment: You've got an error - you need to escape your forward slashes. preg_match is returning false

Comment: also you need to escape the . in .com.

Comment: Your pattern in invalid. So it should show error. check your error log. Check your pattern. what you want.

Comment: Additionally, if you want `$domain` to be matched literally you should use [preg_quote()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) and hand over the regex delimiter you used. Otherwise regex special characters like the `.` in your string can match things you don't expect.

Comment: If you insert your pattern into http://regex101.com it will automatically test it for you and detect errors. You could have avoided having to ask this question in the first place: http://regex101.com/r/bD3gD7 and a working solution: http://regex101.com/r/uV0eV4 (note, I changed the . in stackoverflow.com to \.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at your pattern, it's this

```
/^http(s)?://(([a-z]+)\.)*stackoverflow.com/
```

The delimiter is used as a matching character, and if you had errors turned on, you'd get a ["Unknown modifier"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026387/why-preg-replace-throws-me-a-unknown-modifier-error) error. So first tip: [TURN ERROR REPORTING ON](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)!

To fix it, try using a different delimiter, e.g. `{}`, as it's easier to read than loads of [leaning toothpicks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)...

```
{^http(s)?://(([a-z]+)\.)*stackoverflow.com}
```

The other problem is the dot in the `$domain` becomes a wildcard match - anytime you insert unknown data into a regex, get in the habit of using [preg_quote](http://php.net/preg_quote) to escape it, e.g.

```
$pattern = "{^http(s)?://(([a-z]+)\.)*" . preg_quote($domain, '{') . "}";
```

(Note - nice catch from stema in the comments: if you use a different delimiter, you must pass that preg_quote. It's clever enough to spot paired delimiters, so if you pass `{` it will also escape `}`.)

Comment: +1 for adding `preg_quote($domain)` to your answer. But shouldn't you add the delimiter as parameter, like `preg_quote($string, '/')`? But I have no idea, how you can add it, if you use a pair of brackets as delimiters.

Comment: that's a really good point - I checked and if you pass '{' it will escape '}' too. I will amend.

Comment: I understood what is my problem now. I tried { } but I didn't know preg_quote ... - Why when I'm adding a slash at the end, it didn't work ? Like this : "{^http(s)?://(([a-z]+)\.)*".preg_quote($domain, '{')."/}"    (I want to catch this to avoid domain like stackoverflow.com.eu ...) Sorry for my stupid question ... but regex in PHP is not my friend ^^

Comment: Oh ... ok it's maybe my $domain which was wrong ... :) - Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely getting an error and `preg_match` is returning false, as you are not escaping your forward slashes in your expression. Either use something else like a `#` as the expression delimeter or escape any forward slashes to stop the parser from trying to end the expression (`/` should be `\/` - or change the `/` at either end to be `#`)

```
//Quick fix to yours
$pattern = "/^http(s)?:\/\/(([a-z]+)\.)*".preg_quote($domain,'/')."/";
//More legible fix
$pattern = '#^https?://(([a-z]+)\.)*'.preg_quote($domain,'#').'#';
```

Note that you don't need parenthesis around the s in https (unless you're hoping to capture it)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your forward slashes and the `.` in the domain name

```
$domain = "stackoverflow.com";

$uriToTest = "http://stackoverflow.com/";

$escapedDomain = str_replace('.', '\.', $domain);

$pattern = "/^http(s)?:\/\/(([a-z]+)\.)*".$escapedDomain."/";

echo preg_match($pattern, $uriToTest);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were using [T-Regx](https://github.com/Danon/T-Regx), then this exception would be thrown immediately:

```
$domain = "stackoverflow.com";
$uriToTest = "http://stackoverflow.com/";

try
{
    pattern("/^http(s)?://(([a-z]+)\.)*" . $domain . '/')->match($uriToTest);
}
catch (SafeRegexException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();    // `Unknown modifier '/'`
}
```

But also!! T-Regx can automatically add delimiters, so you can go

```
pattern("^http(s)?://(([a-z]+)\.)*" . $domain)->match($uriToTest);
```

and it would automatically add a suitable delimiter for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
  $domain = "stackoverflow.com";

  $uriToTest = "http://stackoverflow.com/";

  $pattern = "^http(s)?://(([a-z]+)\.)*" . $domain . "^";

  preg_match($pattern, $uriToTest, $matches);
  print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Why are you using the start of string anchor `^` as regex delimiter?

Comment: Inorder to avoid error.
preg_match delimiter must be started from backslash.
you can write in this way as well

  $pattern = "^\http(s)?://(([a-z]+)\.)*".$domain."^";

Comment: I agree, I think that's confusing advice

Comment: But you are introducing another error. The OP already used the regex special character `^` in the regex to match the start of the string.