# Unknown modifier '/' preg_replace()

Tags: twitter, preg-replace

I was making a Twitter Feed for myself and I'm stuck, I have really o idea how to solve this problem.

Error:
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '/'

Code:

```
$tweetText = preg_replace('/(http://|(www.\))(([^\s<]{4,68})[^\s<]*)/', '<a href="http://$2$3" target="_blank">$1$2$4</a>', $tweetText);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why preg\_replace throws me a "Unknown modifier" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026387/why-preg-replace-throws-me-a-unknown-modifier-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: preg\_replace(): Unknown modifier '\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705399/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your delemiter in the regexString (`http://`).
Use another delemiter instead (e.g. `#`).

#### The Explanation behind the error-message:

`preg_replace` thinks that your string is terminated at the first slash of `http://`. Since the modifiers follow after the delemiter which is `/` in your case, it thinks, that the second slash has to be a modifier. There is no modifier `/` - so it crashes

Comment: Now I got this error with using #.


Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 40 in

Comment: It would be nice to know which text you try to match. For example i see `(www.\)` in the code which maybe should be `(www\.)` instead. I dont know till I get an example text ;)

Comment: You couldn't just add a simple text above in your post? This link is crap. I still don't know which stuff should be replaced. Looks like links - but which one? Subdomain? No Subdomain? www or no www? Please just add some sample links in your post!

Comment: Oh - didnt read "It worked". Well - then its nice ^^. Anyway: would be nice for better understanding when you add the samplelinks. Other people can get the problem better then.